# Regexp with formvalidation changes result after each character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a validator on a input text for a file name using a regexp.

This is the regexp `/^[^<>:"\/\\|?*]*$/gi`

This is the test site https://regex101.com/r/4hdrzh/2

It should return false if any of the chars in `[]` are present.

While using FormValidation (https://formvalidation.io/) slightly older version, I see the following behaviour

1. If I have ANY invalid character (eg, : \ etc) the input will always be invalid (great)
2. If I have ONLY valid characters, the validator says that the field is invalid and then valid after each character I type (bad)

Example

```
"a" -> valid
"ab" -> invalid
"abc" -> valid
"abcd" -> invalid
```

It's swapping between valid/invalid for no reason.

Is this is a regexp issue or the formvalidator plugin?

Comment: Remove the `g` flag.

Comment: Thank you. Why does it work on the test site?

Comment: A lot works on a test site. It does not mean the regex will work in the target environment. But the point is that at a regex testing site, you test against a *single multiline string*, while in code, you test it on a set of individual strings.